# How to enable the CONFIG_PM_ADVANCED_DEBUG kernel configuration option

Tags: power-management, battery, powertop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is kernel configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21868/what-is-kernel-configuration)

I'm trying to save the battery power. For that i'm using powertop and one suggestion is "Enable the CONFIG_PM_ADVANCED_DEBUG kernel configuration option.". I have no idea how to make this.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question: [What is kernel configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21868/what-is-kernel-configuration)